quarkus refreshes tokens too late
I have implemented a small REST service as a Quarkus (3.13.3/ 3.15.1) application.
This also calls other APIs and has to authorize itself using bearer tokens.
It follows the guideline: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client. This means that quarkus itself takes over the token management. And 99% of the time everything is fine.
These tokens are valid for 5 minutes.
The problem is that the service is very busy. It often happens that the end of the token's validity falls exactly on a new request.
In this case, Quarkus does not perform a token refresh, but uses the token again. The counterpart rejects it as expired.
In the documentation I found the property quarkus.oidc.token.refresh-token-time-skew=30S. However, I cannot start my application with it.
The error message appears:

The 'quarkus.oidc.token.refresh-token-time-skew' property can only be enabled for WEB_APP application types

The alternative property quarkus.oidc.token.forced-jwk-refresh-interval=4M does not generate an error when starting - but it also has no effect.
My application is not a web app, so I do not want to set the property quarkus.oidc.application-type=hybrid. Especially since I do not know exactly what its effects are.
As soon as I activate it, the error message

'web-app' applications must have 'quarkus.oidc.authorization-path' and 'quarkus.oidc.token-path' properties set when the discovery is disabled.>

appears.
Does anyone have any advice?

Please follow https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/44045, thanks

My error was successfully identified elsewhere:


Firstly, I have to use quarkus.oidc-client.refresh-token-time-skew ("oidc-client") and not quarkus.oidc.token.refresh-token-time-skew.


And secondly, it must of course be bound to the tenants (if available). This means that in my case, quarkus.oidc-client.b2c.refresh-token-time-skew is set.


